# PFImageView -loadInBackground fails with error Code=150

Tags: ios, image, connection, parse-platform

So, I am trying to load an image that exists on my database, into a `PFImageView`

**MyAccount.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *profilePic;
```

**MyAccount.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *cUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    // Get the user's profile pic

    if(cUser[PF_USER_PIC]) {

        NSLog(@"cUser[PF_USER_PIC] exists, description: %@",
                                      [cUser[PF_USER_PIC] description]);

        self.profilePic.file = cUser[PF_USER_PIC];

        [self.profilePic loadInBackground:
         ^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

             if (!error)
                 NSLog(@"profilePic loadInBackground completed");
             else {
                 NSLog(@"profilePic loadInBackground failed with error: %@", error);

             }
        }];
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this is never successful

```
2014-09-04 17:53:03.668 Rally[10281:60b]
 cUser[PF_USER_PIC] exists, description: <PFFile: 0x17b070e80>

2014-09-04 17:53:03.972 Rally[10281:2ca3f]
 profilePic loadInBackground failed with error:
 Error Domain=Parse Code=150 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 150.)"
```

I can't seem to find a solution via googling (not many results). Can anybody shed some light on what *might* be happening here?

Note that I can get `saveInBackground` working a charm. It's just the inbound direction I'm struggling with!

EDIT: **Further information**

I have tried using a UIImageView instead of a PFImageView, and linking that up instead. Here is the code:

```
PFFile *imageData = (PFFile *)cUser[PF_USER_PIC];
[imageData getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:
 ^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"getDataInBackground error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"getDataInBackground SUCCESS");
        self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }

}];
```

This appears to work well:

```
2014-09-09 12:30:31.822 Rally[2266:60b]
 cUser[PF_USER_PIC] exists, description: <PFFile: 0xaaa2080>
2014-09-09 12:30:31.835 Rally[2266:60b]
 getDataInBackground SUCCESS
```

Yet, still not image appears!

Last but not least, if I replace `[UIImage imageWithData:data]` with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_local_image"]`, this works perfectly. So the `UIImageView` is definitely hooked up.

Comment: Maybe try casting the profile pic? `self.profilePic.file = (PFFile *)cUser[PF_USER_PIC];`

Comment: The error code says that it could not convert the data to an image, could be that the profile picture of this user is empty/corrupted? https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFConstants.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kPFErrorInvalidImageData

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the suggestions. I tried explicitly casting, but it made no difference. Not a surprise as the logs show that it already recognises the object as a PFFile. I also tried changing my facebook pic but no joy. Same error. Finally, I have made doubly sure that the saveInBackground completes successfully when the user logs in and it does. Helllllp! :-)

Comment: Also note that I can't get ANY of my PFImageViews to work, anywhere in the app. Very bizarre. Could this be an issue with my account?

Comment: My latest edit suggests that the image may well be corrupted. But I have tried this with multiple images now @BjörnKaiser

Comment: @terrafirma9    just tagging you

Comment: Just wondering, are you calling initWithFrame on the PFImageView? I was debugging something related today with a colleague and you need to init it with a frame, otherwise it will just be 0x0. Just a long shot

Comment: I'm using storyboards, so I thought there was no need? I will try this however, thank you.

Comment: I just checked my parse.com data browser and, while the PFFile objects appear to be there, clicking on them downloads an empty file (zero bytes). Seems odd. Perhaps I am doing something wrong with my upload?